# Looking for a YA book about a brother and sister forced to work in space

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, space

I remember reading this book, or books, probably 6+ years ago which I borrowed from the school library.

The book centres on a boy (teenager I think) who is forced to work for some guy (maybe alien) in space along with other children/teenagers. He gets his arm chopped off at one point and gets a prosthetic which can do a lot of cool things (because plot). The group tries to escape at some point but they get caught and are forced to get tracking implants in their arms. The main character has a younger sister. Not sure if it takes place in our solar system or in outer space but I think there is a part where they mention their father was born on Earth (not sure though). I believe the story takes place in the distant future.

Thank you for the help in advance. I have recently been thinking about the books I used to read as a young teenager as I have not read a book in many years unfortunately.

Comment: I am looking for this book too! I have posted the search on reddit and livejournal http://whatwasthatbook.livejournal.com/3335374.html
https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/5hhax8/tomt_help_with_unknown_fantasy_book/ I read it in the 5th grade about 7 years ago, and am very interested in finding it.

Comment: Wow I just read your posts and I had no idea it was a trilogy. I think I only read the first book. I hope someone knows what we are talking about. If someone comments on your posts please let me know.